# Execute build.xml with Maven

Tags: svn, maven-2, svn-checkout

Is it possible to execute `build.xml` script with Maven?

This script checksout all my projects and subprojects and I've just got used to using maven, didn't really use much of an ant before and I know ant can be used with Maven. So my question is: how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm really not a big fan of this approach (either use Ant, or Maven, but not a bastard mix) but you can use an external `build.xml` with the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"
              classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
            <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
              <target name="test"/>
            </ant>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And then run `mvn antrun:run` (or put the configuration inside an `execution` if you want to bind the AntRun plugin to a lifecycle phase, refer to the [Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) page).

**Update:** If you are using things from ant-contrib, you need to declare it as dependency of the plugin. I've updated the plugin configuration to reflect this. Also note the `taskdef` element that I've added (I'm not sure you need the `classpathref` attribute though).

Comment: ${basedir} is which location?next to the pom.xml ? or ?

Comment: @Gandalf Yes, `${basedir}` represents the directory containing pom.xml

Comment: I tried this using v1.7 of the antrun plugin and it seems the goal is now run e.g: `mvn antrun:run`

Answer (score 0):

You can execute ant scripts via the [Maven-Ant Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/), but why do you need Ant to checkout your project? Haven't you organized your sub-projects to be in the same tree?

Comment: I place ant target between tasks tags and I get this error `Problem: failed to create task or type target
Cause: The name is undefined.`

Comment: @khmarbaise `Haven't you organized your sub-projects to be in the same tree` - what do you mean ?